# Tilegrid error in Phonegap

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm constantly having this error:

```
06-27 10:19:40.503: E/TileGrid(24474): Unexpected portion:left, top, right, bottom 0.000000 0.000000 -0.002500 0.018672<br>
06-27 10:19:40.503: E/TileGrid(24474): Unexpected portion:left, top, right, bottom 0.000000 0.000000 -0.002500 1.000000<br>
06-27 10:19:40.503: E/TileGrid(24474): Unexpected portion:left, top, right, bottom 0.000000 0.000000 -0.002500 1.000000<br>
06-27 10:19:40.503: E/TileGrid(24474): Unexpected portion:left, top, right, bottom 0.000000 0.000000 -0.002500 1.000000<br>
06-27 10:19:40.503: E/TileGrid(24474): Unexpected portion:left, top, right, bottom 0.000000 0.000000 -0.002500 1.000000<br>
06-27 10:19:40.503: E/TileGrid(24474): Unexpected portion:left, top, right, bottom 0.000000 0.010391 -0.002500 1.000000<br>
```

I'm using `Phonegap 3.5.0, JQuery 2.1.1 and JQuery Mobile 1.4.2` (targeting Android), and had this error before (in another apps), but it didn't affect the functionalities. This time, however, in my multipage app, it seems to be affecting the pagecontainer('change', 'mypage') method... the page transition works before the error, but after that, it only changes pages by 5 (I'm using swipe events, so it needs 5 swipes to change page, and jumps from 1 to 5, e.g.). 
The error occurs sometimes after 2 or 3 page changes, other times after 50, so I can't figure it out...

I found this error message in TileGrid.cpp, on android (line 357):
http://osxr.org/android/source/external/webkit/Source/WebCore/platform/graphics/android/rendering/TileGrid.cpp  
...but couldn't find a solution.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem and will answer in case someone have the same issue: the problem was I was using JQuery 2.1.1, and JQMobile was expected to work correctly only with 1.9+ versions (it was explained on the documentation).

Changing to JQuery 1.11.1 made page transitions work correctly.